# Will importing my Firebase app to the new Firebase 3 console break anything?

Tags: firebase

Reading the documentation at  https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web it seems that I can upgrade to the new firebase console without changing or altering my code, and then make those changes when I am ready? Can anyone confirm that importing my firebase app to the new Firebase 3 console will not break anything?

The breaking changes come from actually using the new library, not upgrading to the new console. Correct?

UPDATE: We upgraded to Firebase 3 console and have experienced no issues in the first month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on a Java project and Firebase last month (in Java, not android), and after i upgraded the console i didn't noticed any difference.

I did noticed 2-3 weeks ago that the `rules` has been changed, but i guess it changed in the legacy too.

Comment: Thank you. I can't think of any reason why javascript would be different, but knowing that it worked for you is helpful.